# How to resize width of columns to data and stretch the last section together in Qt TableView

Tags: c++, qt

Anyone knows how to fit the column width to the data in a TableView and then stretch the final column to the size remaining on the widget?

I've tried:

```
_ui->tableView->resizeColumnsToContents();
_ui->tableView->horizontalHeader()->setStretchLastSection(true);
```

But only the `resizeColumnToContent()` work. The last section is unstretched.

Is it even possible without having to dynamically calculate the width manually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nethermind. For prosperity here's the solution:

```
_ui->tableView->resizeColumnsToContents();
_ui->tableView->horizontalHeader()->setSectionResizeMode( 3, QHeaderView::Stretch );
```

In this case the last column is `3`.